# Magento 2 : Error opening customer page (admin)

Tags: magento2

Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config, Argument 1 passed to Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /Magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php

**The above error appearing when opening customer from admin, any thoughts how can i resolve it ?**

Comment: Any idea how can i solve this ?

Comment: Any idea how can i solve this ?